# bind a texture before draw it (webgl)

Tags: webgl

My code works but i am wondering why !

I have 2 textures :

```
    uniform sampler2D uSampler0;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler1;


    void main() {
        vec4 color0 = texture2D(uSampler0, vTexCoord);
        vec4 color1 = texture2D(uSampler1, vTexCoord);
        gl_FragColor = color0 * color1;
    }
```

and my js code

```
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,my_texture_ZERO); 
    gl.uniform1i(program.uSampler0,0); 

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,my_texture_ONE); 
    gl.uniform1i(program.uSampler1); 

    // uncomment one of the 3, it works.
    // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, my_texture_ZERO);
    // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, my_texture_ONE);
    // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture_FOR_PURPOSE_ONLY);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

before gl.draw, i have tested the 3 bindings,
each one works !

So, i do not understand the real pipeline underlying .

Thanks for some explanations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is invalid

```
gl.uniform1i(program.uSampler1);
```

You're not passing a value to the sampler

The way WebGL texture units work is they are global state inside WebGL

`gl.activeTexture` sets the texture unit all other texture commands effect. For each texture unit there are 2 bind points, `TEXTURE_2D` and `TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`.

You can think of it like this

```
gl = {
  activeTextureUnit: 0,
  textureUnits: [
     { TEXTURE_2D: null: TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, },
     { TEXTURE_2D: null: TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, },
     { TEXTURE_2D: null: TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, },
     ...
  ],
};
```

`gl.activeTexture` just does this

```
gl.activeTexture = function(unit) {
 gl.activeTextureUnit = unit - gl.TEXTURE0;
};
```

`gl.bindTexture` does this

```
gl.bindTexture = function(bindPoint, texture) {
  gl.textureUnits[gl.activeTextureUnit][bindPoint] = texture;
};
```

`gl.texImage2D` and `gl.texParamteri` look up which texture to work with like this

```
gl.texImage2D = function(bindPoint, .....) {
  var texture = gl.textureUnits[gl.activeTextureUnit][bindPoint];
  // now do something with texture
```

In other words, inside WebGL there is a global array of texture units. `gl.activeTexture` and `gl.bindTexture` manipulate that array.

`gl.texXXX` manipulate the textures themselves but they reference the textures indirectly through that array.

`gl.uniform1i(someSamplerLocation, unitNumber)` sets the shader's uniform to look at a particular index in that array of texture units.

Comment: great, i am going tu use it as a "reference card" !

Comment: See also this article : https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html

Answer (score 1):

It's working correctly because in the presented code you are sending the appropriate uniforms for the samplers.

First texture was set to unit 0 by calling glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) and was bound afterward. Then a switch was made to unit1.

At that point there were two separate bound textures in each unit.

At the end these units were passed as the uniforms for samplers - which is how to indicate which texture should be in a sampler: in this case passing 0 corresponding to the GL_TEXTURE0 unit to the first uniform and analogousy for the second uniform.

Probably even without uncommenting these lines - things should work.

Comment: ok, but it doesnt work if i make a  : `gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null)`, so what the binding before draw stand for ?

Comment: The binding stands for setting a texture in the active unit. You've previously activated unit 0 by calling glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);  . As you could guess - the GL_TEXTURE0 indicates the 0 unit. After that you've bound a texture by calling the glBindTexture. If you call glBindTexture with null (or 0 to be explicit) you are removing a texture from an unit. Also keep in mind that you can switch the active units but by switching active units you dont discard changes in the previously active unit, so a texture bound there - stays there.

Comment: Okk...and if there is no explicit active unit before doing a  bind, then the binding deal with unit 0 by default.